# When a Pokemon successfully calls for help, can a different Pokemon show up next time?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I'm trying to catch an Umbreon and I found an Eevee, but so far the Eevee has only been calling other Eevee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a chance you can still get an Umbreon/Espeon. However, I believe it is more common for Eevees to appear from SOS, so it will take more time to find (as you have experienced).

Comment: thank youuuu I feel like evolving eevee would be easier than haha

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/SOS_Battle) states *Eevee* can call for help *Eevee*, *Espeon* (only during the day) or *Umbreon* (only at night).

And according to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/sosbattle.shtml):

> In the encounter listings there are up to 8 different rows of Pokémon and when a Pokémon calls for help it will select a random encounter row and give you a Pokémon of the same slot in that row.

So probably most of those slots are *Eevee* and only one is *Umbreon*.

Comment: coool coooooool